# How to grab value out of this nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to iterate over this array of objects, but keep getting errors when I try to map it. It was produced using multi-select from the npm package 'react-select'. Looking for a javascript answer as I'm using it in React.

The example of what I've tried is me just trying to get the value to console.log for now. When I run it, I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I believe I remember running into the issue of having the number in front of an object inside of an array in the past, but I can't figure out what this type of array is called in order to diagnose the issue.

```
this.state.typeOfFruit = [
   0: {label: "label 1", value: "apple"}
   1: {label: "label 2", value: "orange"}
   2: {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} 
]

typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
```

My expected results would be [apple, orange, banana].

****EDIT****

I'm including the code for the react-select multi-select form that is creating the malformed Array. So, the information, upon submit is going through my redux store and into Firebase Firestore. The end results is the malformed array above. This is a larger base of code, so I tried to post everything that should apply to the path of that particular code.

```
class FruitOrderForm extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           typeOfFuit: [],
       }
   }

const fruitOptions = [
   { value: 'apple', label: 'label 1' },
   { value: 'orange', label: 'label 2' },
   { value: 'banana', label: 'label 3' },
]

    handleMultiSelectChange = (typeOfFruit) => {
       this.setState({ typeOfFruit });
  }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.props.updateProfile(this.state)
       document.getElementById("fruitOrderForm").reset();
}

render() {
   typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
   return (
      <div>
         <form id='fruitOrderForm' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            < Select
               id='typeOfFruit'
               value={this.state.typeOfFruit}
               onChange={this.handleMultiSelectChange}
               options={fruitOptions }
               isMulti='true'
               isSearchable='true'
            />
            <button>Update</button>
         </form>
     </div>
  )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const profile = state.firebase.profile

    return{
       profile: profile,
       auth: state.firebase.auth
    } 
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateProfile: (users) => dispatch(updateProfile(users)),
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect([{ collection: 'users'}]))(
FruitOrderForm)
```

My Redux Store Action

```
export const updateProfile = (users) => {
   return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      const profile = getState().firebase.profile
       const userID = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
       firestore.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
          ...profile,
          typeOfConsulting: users.typeOfConsulting
       }).then(() => {
          dispatch({ type: 'UPDATED_PROFILE', profile });
          console.log('update successful')
       }).catch((err) => {
          dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PROFILE_ERROR', err });
          console.log('There was an error', err)
       })
   }
}
```

Then it runs through a reducer

```
const businessProfileReducter = (state = initState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case 'CREATE_BUSINESS_PROFILE': 
        console.log('created business profile', action.businessProfile)
        return state;
      case 'CREATE_BUSINES_PROFILE_ERROR': 
        console.log('create business profile error', action.err);
        return state;
      default:
        return state;
   }
}

export default businessProfileReducter;
```

then Root Reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   auth: authReducer,
   businessProfile: businessProfileReducer,
   firestore: firestoreReducer,
   firebase: firebaseReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

I believe that should cover everything. If anyone sees any glaring holes, let me know.

Comment: Are you running code in `strict mode`? Please create a proper variable using `let, const` and then try to access the array element, you might also want to move your array before iterating over it.

Comment: Also, you don't need the tickmarks (unless they're actually in your code, which ain't gonna help you here!). Indenting does the trick. Use tickmarks for inline code like `this` instead of blocks. Welcome and happy hunting.

Comment: @HassanImam, I'm not using strict mode. As for let or const, I'm doing this in react, so it would actually be this.state.typeOfFruit, I just left that off as I felt it was inconsequential to my question. I added it in, just in case it isn't as inconsequential as I thought. Also, I'm accessing the array afterwards because it's set into my state.

Comment: @D_N. Thanks. First time posting. I appreciate the insight on the backticks.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like some syntax error in the way array is defined , array should not contain a key value pair.
Please check the code snippet below. 
Hope it helps.

```js
typeOfFruit = [
   {label: "label 1", value: "apple"},
   {label: "label 2", value: "orange"},
   {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} 
]

typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
```

Comment: Yes. I agree that it shouldn't look like what I have, but it does. That is exactly the issue that I'm having. I believe there's a way to get rid of the numbers before the object, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

```js
typeOfFruit = [
   {label: "label 1", value: "apple"},
   {label: "label 2", value: "orange"},
   {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} 
]

var newArray = typeOfFruit.map(x => {
  return x.value
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is malformed, yes, but there are two possible ways to fix it.

### Array of Objects

One, the cleaner one, is:

```js
const typeOfFruit = [
   {label: "label 1", value: "apple"},
   {label: "label 2", value: "orange"},
   {label: "label 3", value: "banana"}
]

typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(fruit.value))
```

### Array with Index Key-Value Pair

However, if you need the `0: { ... }` format, you can use `Object.values` (if [not supporting IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=object.values)) and get the first value of each, like so:

```js
const typeOfFruit = [
    {0: { label: "label 1", value: "apple"} },
    {1: {label: "label 2", value: "orange"} },
    {2: {label: "label 3", value: "banana"} }
]

typeOfFruit.map((fruit) => console.log(Object.values(fruit)[0].value) )
```

Comment: I don't need the numbers. I wish the numbers weren't there because that is what is causing my issue. Maybe I need to redefine my issue as react-select is sending a malformed array. I'm going to edit my question to include the react-select multi-select portion that is creating the bad array.

Comment: That's a much different question. Good luck, but it may be best to make a whole new question for that part.